# ASP.NET Web Form Delete Password field auto populated

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am developing an system by using ASP.Net Web Form. In one of the page, the password field is auto populated due to user have saved the username and password for login. However, in the particular page. I don't want username and passoword is auto populated in the label field. I try to empty the field in onPostInit of the page. However, it does not work. The username and password label field still auto populated due to user have saved the password in default chrome system.

Any solutions, I can empty the username and password field in the particular page in ASP.Net Web Form?

Comment: Can we see your markup code

Comment: Can't you set the `autocomplete` attribute on the form element? I.e., `autocomplete="off"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want the entire form to not use any autocompletion, you can set the autocomplete property to be off.

> autocomplete="off"

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
```

Additonally you can do this on a control level basis for whichever textboxes you wish not to use the autocomplete functionality.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="username"  Runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Not sure why but I just got a random notification from this post. I'm glad this worked out for you. I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer to close out this post.